# Converting a mmm-yy date in string format to date format

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an excel document that lists dates in mmm-yy format as a string (they've been copied in from a pdf). I need to be able to determine the number of days between these dates, however excel misunderstands them as mmm-dd format.

For example: I need to find the number of days between Jun-11 and Jun-13. Say they are in A1 and B1 respectively. In the next cell I type "=B1-A1". Number of days should be 730, but excel puts out 2. It calculates June 13th, 2014 - June 11th, 2014.

When I try to change the format to date it will give me something like Jun-11 -> Jun-14 (still reading it as June 11th, 2014).

I've tried to concatenate the dates to make a full date ("Jun"+"-1-"+"11") = Jun-1-11, but it still comes out as a string and I cannot perform the necessary operations with it.

Is there a way to easily correct the format of these dates? I could do this manually with Replace but there are several hundred.

Comment: http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/convert-text-value-date-excel

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I found that article before I posted my question. The problem is the text portion of the date. Simply using DATEVALUE still gives me June 1st 2014, and using a concatenation then using DATEVALUE doesn't work because it doesn't understand the "Jun" in Jun-01-11.

Comment: So when you go into the format options for these cells, they are **general**? When you put them in a custom format, they change value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First suggestion:

Highlight the Excel column holding your date strings, and Format the cells to be "General" instead of "Text".  Excel should then figure out they are dates, and will probably convert them properly.

Second suggestion (more directly answering the question):

You can use [MID](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/mid-midb-functions-HP010342690.aspx), [LEFT](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/left-leftb-functions-HP005209153.aspx) and/or [RIGHT](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/right-rightb-HP005209237.aspx?CTT=1) to manually pick apart the date string, and then use DATE to convert it to an actual date type.

[Reference (see Option #3)](http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/convert-text-value-date-excel)

DATE Syntax: DATE(year, month, day)

So say A1 contains "JUN-13"...

`=DATE(CONCATENATE("20",RIGHT(A1,2)),MONTH(1&LEFT(A1,3)),1)`

[CONCATENATE](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/concatenate-function-HP010342288.aspx) is used to join the string "20" to the string representing the year, to ensure it doesn't think "13" is "1913" during conversion.

The [MONTH](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/month-function-HP010062291.aspx) function is used to get the number of the month based on the provided text string.  the `1&` bit is to force MONTH to join the 1 to the first three characters of the cell (say "1Jun"). Excel recognises that as a date format and treats it like a date for the MONTH function to then extract the month number.

[Reference](http://a4accounting.com.au/excel-convert-text-month-to-the-month-number/)

Once those are done, [DATE](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/date-function-HP010062283.aspx) is used to combine the bits into a final date (using a "Day" of 1).

Using your example data and the above formula to convert them and put the results in new cells, and then performing the subtraction on the cells with the results gives me 731 (leap year? :) ).

Comment: This is exactly what I'd recommend as well. +1

Comment: Fantastic! This worked perfectly. The "MONTH(1&LEFT" was what I needed. Thanks!